# Git Edits "Lost in Space"

Tags: git

The following is a `gitk` representation of my repository:

[image: Depiction of a Git repository]

The part that confuses me is that rebellious pink triangle near the high-lighted entry. It's a little nebula of code that is not on any branch. The stash is empty, so it's not hiding there either.

I don't need this code, but I'm bothered that it's still lurking... somewhere near the fringes of my known repository.

How can I find it and extirpate it?

The problem may have been caused by trying to rebase a branch and then trying to abort that operation through resets and checkouts.

Comment: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash

Answer (score 3):

That appears to be some changes that were stashed when you started gitk, then removed from the stash followed by asking gitk to **Update** the display.

When a reference is deleted (as with removing something from the stash) the referenced commits and other objects aren't immediately removed by git. Instead those objects remain in git's object store for a period of time before they become eligible for garbage collection. This also happens for objects that are made obsolete by doing a rebase or `commit --amend`.  Also when the **Update** (<kbd>F5</kbd>) command in gitk is used that does not cause it to remove commits from the display even if they are no longer referenced.

To clean up the display in gitk you can use the **Reload** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>) command rather than **Update**.  As for removing those items from the object store that will eventually happen automatically.  You can force that to happen sooner by using `git gc` specifying a date with the `--prune` option, but unless the space being consumed by those objects is causing you problems I wouldn't recommend doing that.